# How can I open a specific page of another app from my app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m trying to build a functionality where i want to open the settings page of WhatsApp from a simple onTap gesture in my app. To launch WhatsApp I’m using this dependency: 
https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps

However it isn’t helping me open the settings page specifically. 
Is there a tool available for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this by passing the package name of the another application.

```
dependencies:
  android_intent: ^0.3.5
```

Comment: So the app is opening with the existing dependency, device_apps. I just wanted to open the specific page, in this case settings page of WhatsApp, the app which is being launched. Any idea how this can be done using android_intent?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp has a URL scheme to launch the app and send a message to a phone number.

[iOS Url Scheme](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013)

[Android Url Scheme](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012)

But I don't think that you will be able to launch WhatsApp settings directly.